# How to fix target framework reference for windows application pack in visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-4.6.1

I have an asp web server target framework is .NET Framework 4.6.1,

```
<TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
```

I would like to add this project to a Windows application package and generate an installer. After I build the package, an error message:

> target'net461' it cannot be referenced by a project that targets
>   '.NETCore,Version=v5.0'.
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Project '..\Example\Example.csproj' targets 'net461'. It cannot
>   be referenced by a project that targets
>   '.NETCore,Version=v5.0'.  ExamplePackage  C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets 1653

I think it because windows application packaging has a default target framework but I have no idea how to change it. Could someone help me with this ?

Comment: Similar problem here, have you found a solution? In my case i'm using Wix toolset to generate the installer

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution:

You should specify on the project xml, under each reference, which target framework to use, like this:

`<SetTargetFramework>TargetFramework=net461</SetTargetFramework>`

**Complete example for a given reference**

```
    <ProjectReference Include="theProject.csproj">
      <Name>theProject</Name>
      <Project>{46e70050-559c-442f-b47d-99a3ad73afd3}</Project>
      <Private>True</Private>
      <DoNotHarvest>True</DoNotHarvest>
      <RefProjectOutputGroups>Binaries;Content;Satellites</RefProjectOutputGroups>
      <RefTargetDir>INSTALLFOLDER</RefTargetDir>
      <SetTargetFramework>TargetFramework=net461</SetTargetFramework>
    </ProjectReference>
```